# How to exclude meteor tests and run only the package tests (meteor 0.6.0+)

Tags: meteor

With the new meteor release 0.6.0 it's possible to use the meteor testing framework for app tests too. 
Is it possible to run only the app-tests in the app packages, without all of the meteor tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply run: `meteor test-packages <package name(s)>`. For more information, `meteor test-packages --help`.

Comment: btw. can i use one the phantomjs test-runner somehow, too?

Comment: meteor test-packages --driver-package test-in-console --port 4711

Comment: @JensZastrow What is the port 4711 for?